# How to save state to var/const and stop it updating?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm working on a filter for a `ListView`, a way to be able to sort/order/etc the items. Basically I'm saving the parameters in `state` and they're updated via some toggles/select-fields on a `<Modal>`.

The modal has a cancel & apply button. If you select **apply** after changing filters, the `ListView`'s contents would be updated. However if they were to select **cancel** after changing settings, they would be reverted to whatever it was before the filter modal was launched.

So I'm doing this:

```
// Update filterValues state
adjustFilterValue(filterSection, newValue) {

    if ( this.state.hasAdjustedFilters === false ) {

        const filterValues = this.state.filterValues;

        this.setState({
            hasAdjustedFilters: true
        })
    }

    var newFilterValues = defaultFilterValues;

    newFilterValues[filterSection] = newValue;

    this.setState({
        filterValues: newFilterValues
    })
}
```

However whenever I adjust `this.state.filterValues` - `newFilterValues` get's updated too.

How can I save & *isolate* an object from state?

Answer (score -1):

You can store your initial state by using lifecycle hooks:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this._initialState = this.state;
}
```

Later on, in a case of revert, simply `setState(this._initialState);`